# Comma between two items before the equal sign

Tags: python

There is a program that has

```
 x, wrap_flag_x = wrap(x + cos(angle), N)
```

My question is, what is it doing when you put a comma in between two things to the left of the equals sign.

I get for example x = 5 so is it the same as x,y = 5 where x= 5 and y = 5?

Comment: thank you for the quick response!

Comment: I guess asking Google would have been even faster...

Comment: No, to assign both you'd need `x, y = 5, 5`, or `x = y = 5`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at what happens when I do this:

```
In [1]: x,y = 1,2

In [2]: x
Out[2]: 1

In [3]: y
Out[3]: 2
```

Thus, `wrap(x + cos(angle), N)` returns two values, and the first of those values gets assigned to `x` while the second gets assigned to `wrap_flag_x`. Think about it this way:

```
In [4]: def myfunc():
   ...:     return 'a', 'b'
   ...: 

In [5]: x,y = myfunc()

In [6]: x
Out[6]: 'a'

In [7]: y
Out[7]: 'b'

In [8]: myfunc()
Out[8]: ('a', 'b')
```